# How do I completley delete Psensor?

Tags: 14.04, psensor

I uninstalled it from the Ubuntu Software Centre but it's still here.

I found the files for it but they have a lock on them. Here are some pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCDXM.jpg

Comment: What is that directory you made a screenshot of?

Comment: It wasn’t a directory, I searched it in 'Computer' and they came up so Im assuming they are the files.

Comment: Right click and choose "open item location".

Comment: On all of them?

Comment: Here: computer/etc/xdg/autostart for pensor.desktop

Answer (score 0):

The lock means it's owned by root, and you can't access or delete it.

To uninstall completely, open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Copy and Paste this command by right click Paste, then press Enter:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge psensor
```

Then type your password (no `*` will appear, keep typing).

Psensor will be removed.

---

If that doesn't work, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install psensor && sudo apt-get remove --purge psensor
```

Comment: 4 of them are still there and the actual program is still working

Comment: http://imgur.com/aQIAiqd

Comment: @Isaac I can't see imgur images at the moment, my internet is being stupid. I've added another command, could you run that.

Comment: I tried that and it made alot more of psensor files ;-; and the program is still working fine :c

Comment: when your internet works have a look at this http://imgur.com/EDh0JeZ

Comment: Hu that's strange. Have you restarted since? If you're not in the middle of something, that may help.

Comment: I will try that now

Comment: They are still there :c

Comment: Can you still open PSensor?

Comment: It looks like the actual program is gone but alot of the files are still there 20 of them

Comment: run `sudo apt-get remove psensor`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YFEmAFFN

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Is there a way to activate root?

Comment: Hu? Use sudo - `sudo apt-get autoremove`.